# Java - JUnit how to do?

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I have the following method and how can I do the JUnit testing on it?

Parser is my constructor, which I am also using as my return type of my following method.

As this method is splitting the string in three one, so for that I want to write a unit test case.

I am somehow familiar with JUnit but not that much. Any guidance/ link/ help will be appreciated.

```
public class Example {

    public Parser thirdValueCleanup(String value) {
        String thirdValueValue = value.trim();
        System.out.println("TestData: "+thirdValueValue);
        String firstValueRegex = "[A-z]\\d[A-z]";
        String secondValueRegex = "\\d[A-z]\\d";
        String thirdValueRegex = "[SK|sk]{2}";

        Pattern firstValuePattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\W*("+firstValueRegex+")\\W*.*");
        Pattern secondValuePattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\W*("+secondValueRegex+")\\W*.*");
        Pattern thirdValuePattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\W*("+thirdValueRegex+")\\W*.*");

        String firstValue = "";
        String secondValue = "";
        String thirdValue = "";

        Matcher firstValueMatcher = firstValuePattern.matcher(thirdValueValue);
        if(firstValueMatcher.matches()) {
            firstValue = firstValueMatcher.group(1);  
        }

        Matcher secondValueMatcher = secondValuePattern.matcher(thirdValueValue);
        if(secondValueMatcher.matches()) {
            secondValue = secondValueMatcher.group(1); 
        }

        Matcher thirdValueMatcher = thirdValuePattern.matcher(thirdValueValue);
        if(thirdValueMatcher.matches()) {
            thirdValue = thirdValueMatcher.group(1);
        }

        String FirstValueName = firstValue + " " + secondValue;
        String thirdValueName = thirdValue;

        return new Parser(FirstValueName, thirdValueName);
    }

    public Parser(String firstValue, String secondValue) {
        this.firstValue = firstValue;
        this.secondValue = secondValue; 
    }

    public String getFirstValue() {
        return firstValue;
    }

    public String getSecondValue() {
        return secondValue;
    }
}
```

I tried in my test:

```
public final void testThirdValueCleanup() {

    System.out.println("retrieve");
    String factories = "SK S6V 7L4";
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    Parser expResult = SK S6V 7L4;
    Parser result = parser.thirdValueCleanup(factories);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
```

I got this error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<SK S6V 7L4> but was:<com.example.Parser@379619aa>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:329)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:78)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:86)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals(TestCase.java:253)
    at com.example.ParserTest.testthirdValueCleanup(ParserTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: JUst like any basic junit test case: you call the method with known inputs, then check that the output is what you expect, i.e. a new parser with the expected first and second values. Try something.

Comment: Don't post code in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Okay. I did. you can check now.

Comment: What you posted is not valid Java. It can't even compile.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? like how?

Comment: I suggest that you learn some debugging skills. Start with the stack trace from the test failure and figure out what line of code from your app under test causes the failure. Then back track from there to figure out why the test fails.

Comment: `Parser expResult = SK S6V 7L4;`: that's not Java code.

Comment: Also, JUnit 4 is several years old. Don't use JUnit 3.

Comment: Parser expResult = null; < i am using this at the moment. then i got the error. i don't know how can i call my getters here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Anyone should be able to copy and paste your code and then run it as long as they have the correctly installed tools. We should not have to make any modifications to fix compiler errors, such as adding `class` declarations.

Comment: Also be sure to show the exact code you are using, not some modified version.

Comment: Your test should just have something like `assertEquals("someExpectedFirstValue", result.getFirstValue()); assertEquals("someExpectedSecondValue", result.getSecondValue());`

Comment: assertEquals("someExpectedFirstValue", result.getFirstValue()); assertEquals("someExpectedSecondValue", result.getSecondValue());  < isn't this code is only testing getters not my parser method?

Comment: No. It's testing what the Parser that was created when calling thirdValueCleanup (i.e. result) contains. The result Parser is your output, since that's what the method returns. If you take a dice, and roll it, and ask what the top face of the dice is, you get the result of rolling the dice, don't you?

Comment: i am getting this now junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[AB]> but was:<[]>

Comment: `@Test
 public final void testThirdValue() {
  
  System.out.println("retrieve");
        String factories = " SK S6V 7L4";
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        Parser province = parser.thirdValue(factories);
        
       assertEquals("S6V 7L4", province.getFirstValue()); 
       assertEquals("SK", province.getSecondValue());
 }`

I got result with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@Test
    public final void testThirdValue() {

        System.out.println("retrieve");
        String factories = " BK M6B 7A4";
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        Parser province = parser.thirdValue(factories);

       assertEquals("M6B 7A4", province.getFirstValue()); 
       assertEquals("BK", province.getSecondValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any guidance/ link/ help will be appreciated. thanks

As a simple approach, you might want to try out something within the following lines. As a first step create the test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ExampleTest {
  Example example = new Example();

  @Test
  public void testThirdValueCleanup(){
    //pass some inputs to your function 
    //by exclicitly calling 
    //example.thirdValueCleanup(input params...);

    //a simple test case would be to check if it you get what your expect
    Parser expected = new Parser("set this one as it should be");
    assertEquals(example.thirdValueCleanup(some inputs...), expected);
  }
  /*
  * Here you can define more test cases
  */
}
```

Next you can create a class to run your test:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ExampleTest.class);

      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }

      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

For more information you can consult either [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_writing_tests.htm) tutorial or [getting started by JUnit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started).